# Why am I getting "Instance method 'background(_:alignment:)' requires that 'UIColor' conform to 'View'"?

Tags: swiftui

I would like to understand why am I having issue with the `background()`?

> Instance method 'background(_:alignment:)' requires that 'UIColor' conform to 'View'

```
var body: some View {
    
    Button("MY BUTTON") {
        print("the action")
    }
    .padding()
    .background(Color.black)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .clipShape(Capsule())
}
```

**UPDATE**

Get same thing with this:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Did not you redefine / extension Color? Or maybe this is in some different code?

Comment: set every color using Color sturct. Example: .background(Color.blue)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably created another struct/class called `Color`. Xcode syntax highlighting is different for `Color.black` - this suggests you're not using the SwiftUI `Color`.

Try this calling it explicitly:

```
.background(SwiftUI.Color.black)
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, none of the answers helped me either. What finally worked for me was defining (initialising) the color each time.

```
Text("Hello World").padding.background(Color.init(UIColor(red: 0, green:0, blue:0, alpha: 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax once.

This might work:

```
var body: some View {

    Button(action: {
        print("the action tapped!")
    }) {
        Text("Hello World")
            .padding()
            .background(Color.black)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
       }
}
```

Comment: got same issue :-( (see update from original description)

Comment: .background(SwiftUI.Color.black)  try this by calling SwiftUI.Color explicitly as said by @powell02222